# Is it possible to set custom x-axis values in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

For example I have 5 x-axis values like `{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}`.

```
List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
entries.add(new Entry(1, 0));
entries.add(new Entry(2, 1));
entries.add(new Entry(3, 2));
entries.add(new Entry(4, 3));
entries.add(new Entry(5, 4));
LineDataSet ds = new LineDataSet(entries, "");
LineData data = new LineData(new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}, ds);
```

And I want only `{"1", "2", "4"}` be shown on x-axis on graph.

Is it possible to do with MPAndroidChart?

Comment: Did you found out a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try splitting the string to extract values using string.split method.

```
String string = "1","2","3","4","5";
String[] whole = string.split(",");
String str1 = whole[0]; // 1
String str2 = whole[1]; // 2
String str3 = whole[3]; //4
```

Answer (score 0):

There is **NO** method in the library at present that can achieve this.

Although, this seems reasonably easy to implement. Why not fork the repo and create your own custom method? Additionally, you might also want to try and implement the `XAxisValueFormatter interface` to your advantage.